# Parse Cloud httpRequest does not return a response

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, httprequest, parse-cloud-code

I am calling my Parse Cloud function from a js in my browser. I am doing merely as a test. I am trying to make a GET call to `http://api.geonames.org` . If I execute it in the browser as `http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo` it does work. It returns:

```
{"geonames":[{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Mexico City","countrycode":"MX","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Mexiko-Stadt","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_City","lng":-99.12766456604,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":3530597,"lat":19.428472427036,"population":12294193},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Beijing","countrycode":"CN","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Peking","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing","lng":116.397228240967,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":1816670,"lat":39.9074977414405,"population":11716620},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Manila","countrycode":"PH","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Manila","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manila","lng":120.9822,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":1701668,"lat":14.6042,"population":10444527},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Dhaka","countrycode":"BD","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Dhaka","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhaka","lng":90.40743827819824,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":1185241,"lat":23.710395616597037,"population":10356500},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Seoul","countrycode":"KR","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Seoul","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seoul","lng":126.9784,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":1835848,"lat":37.566,"population":10349312},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Jakarta","countrycode":"ID","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Jakarta","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta","lng":106.84513092041016,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":1642911,"lat":-6.214623197035775,"population":8540121},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Tokyo","countrycode":"JP","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Tokio","wikipedia":"de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo","lng":139.69171,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":1850147,"lat":35.6895,"population":8336599},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Taipei","countrycode":"TW","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Taipeh","wikipedia":"de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taipei","lng":121.531846,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":1668341,"lat":25.047763,"population":7871900},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Bogotá","countrycode":"CO","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Bogotá","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogot%C3%A1","lng":-74.08175468444824,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":3688689,"lat":4.609705849789108,"population":7674366},{"fcodeName":"capital of a political entity","toponymName":"Hong Kong","countrycode":"HK","fcl":"P","fclName":"city, village,...","name":"Hong Kong","wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong","lng":114.157691001892,"fcode":"PPLC","geonameId":1819729,"lat":22.2855225817732,"population":7012738}]}
```

Whereas if I execute it in my Cloud Code as:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("testRequest", function(request , response){
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON',
        params: {
            'north' : '44.1',
            'south' : '-9.9',
            'east' : '-22.4',
            'west' : '55.2',
            'lang' : 'de',
            'username' : 'demo'
        },
        success:function(httpResponse){
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success("success from response.success>>>>");
            console.log('httpResponse->'+ httpResponse.response +'  <<<');
            console.log('data>>'+httpResponse.data);
        },
        error:function(httpResponse){
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            response.error(httpResponse.status);
        }, 
    });
});
```

With a script in my local machine of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("KEY", "KEY");



        Parse.Cloud.run('testRequest', {}, {
          success: function(result) {
            alert(result.httpRequest+"<----RESULT!")
            // result is 'Hello world!'
          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert("Something went wrong"+error.message);
          }
        });
  </script>
```

It returns a 200 status but no data. I made sure I deployed my code, and I see the latest code in the Cloud Code tab in Parse.com, so it's definitely not the case that I have old code running on the cloud.

Do you know how to correctly make a successful GET call from Cloud Code?
Any help regarding this topic or helping me correcting any error in my code is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If it's exactly the code you are running, CloudCode function return a string `success from response.success>>>>`, right? But your JavaScript code try to get `httpRequest` from the string.

Comment: what do you mean? Sorry I could not understand... Are you saying that I should not return `success from response.success>>>>`?

Comment: Yes. I think you should `response.success(httpResponse.text);` and `alert(result);`. The browser alerts the Json `{"geonames":[{"fcodeName":"ca...` now.

Comment: It did it for me! Could you please put your solution as an answer so I can choose it as the solution? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the data from CloudCode by

```
response.success(httpResponse.text);
```

And use the data in JavaScript like this

```
Parse.Cloud.run('testRequest', {}, {
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

You will see the result now.